# Everything imported with "import" gets types but require() doesn't

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

I don't know if this issue is related to VS Code or not. But basically when importing packages in typescript with this syntax

```
import express from "express";
```

I get the type definitions along with the code itself.
But whenever I use

```
const express = require("express");
```

It has the `any` type. This is not `express` specific.

I am new to node.js BTW.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to use `require` to load your modules (because you are in a CommonJS module or for whatever reason), you can still use it with the import statement. It will load the types as well.

```
import express = require('express');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is VS Code related, but out of personal experience, you are right: `import` and `require` work differently. TypeScript only loads type definitions if we use the `import` keyword and not `require`. If using `require`, you'll see types defined as `any`.

So, whenever possible, stick to the `import` keyword, and you will get types loaded and available to be used.